# Trying to send angular dynamic array of promises to express server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-promise

I am trying to send an array of promises to an express app to get data from a mongo database. It seems to behave correctly on the front end. In this example both objects are sent to the server, and are resolved with $q.all. But as I am debugging the server I see both objects are the same. In this case it is the last promise with payload2 that gets resolved 2 times. If I add more promises the correct number gets resolved but they are all values from the last object in the array.

```
   var promises = logCspItemInventoryStatus(payload,result.cspItems);

    return $q.all(promises)
        .then(function(result){
          toastr.success('Items have been logged');
        })
       .catch(function(err){
         toastr.error(err);
       })

var logCspItemInventoryStatus = function (payload,cspItems) {
    var promises = [];
     angular.forEach(cspItems, function(item){
          //I am appending payload with items
           payload.qty=item.checking;
           payload.description=item.description;

          //payload 1 {docId: "55c124f7485684e81d6181fc", by: "Foo Bar", checkIn: false, qty: 2, description: "car"}
          //payload 2 {docId: "55c124f7485684e81d6181fc", by: "Foo2 Bar2", checkIn: false, qty: 1, description: "hall"}

           var p = checkOutCspItem(payload);
          promises.push(p);
    });

    return promises;
 };

//returns a promise
var checkOutData = function(payload) {
  return Csp.update(payload).$promise.then(function(result) {
    return result.data
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you kept modifying the payload param, which is an object and thus passed by reference, so every time you change it it modifies all references of it, including those already added to the array of promises.

```
var promises = logCspItemInventoryStatus(payload,result.cspItems);

    return $q.all(promises)
    .then(function(result){
      toastr.success('Items have been logged');
    })
   .catch(function(err){
     toastr.error(err);
   })

var logCspItemInventoryStatus = function (payload,cspItems) {
var promises = [];
 angular.forEach(cspItems, function(item){
      //I am appending payload with items
       var payloadCopy = angular.copy(payload);
       payloadCopy.qty=item.checking;
       payloadCopy.description=item.description;

      //payload 1 {docId: "55c124f7485684e81d6181fc", by: "Foo Bar", checkIn: false, qty: 2, description: "car"}
      //payload 2 {docId: "55c124f7485684e81d6181fc", by: "Foo2 Bar2", checkIn: false, qty: 1, description: "hall"}

       var p = checkOutCspItem(payloadCopy);
      promises.push(p);
});

return promises;
 };

//returns a promise
var checkOutData = function(payload) {
  return Csp.update(payload).$promise.then(function(result) {
return result.data
   });
  }
```